# How to load a page faster, if I have the same image, repeated over and over again on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

Could I use a JavaScript Image object? If so, can someone give me an example? And could it be done with jQuery?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you're asking.

Comment: @DennisTraub I have an image constantly used on the page, like over 100 times. It's now taking way too long to load, so I was thinking of using something to speed up the loading process.

Comment: the image itself should be cached...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A javascript image object will not save you anything in this case.  The browser will cache the image the first time it is loaded and then retrieve it from the cache any time it is referenced on the page.  Javascript will not help your page load speed for this issue.

Fewer images or smaller images will help.  If you have lots of different images, they can sometimes be combined into a single sprite and then load faster.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you don't have to do anything: browser will just cache remote request to image (or whatever else remote resource) and you can't "duplicate" nodes with actual data in any way.

The only way to somehow go around this scheme for whatever reason is to have data inline in form of [data URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). That way you can have your image or another resource serealized to data URI in JS variable that you can assign to nodes' `src` or similar attribute and avoid any attempts of additional requests.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same image over and over on the same page, the browser will cache it and only load it the 1st time